# Kali - problem with kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5 run.sh

Tags: linux, kali-linux, speech-recognition

I try to launch `run.sh` but it fails. 
Does anyone know how to fix it? 
Text from terminal after launching `run.sh`:

```
There was an error running the SLURM sbatch command.
The command was:
'/usr/bin/sbatch -o exp/make_mfcc/train/q/make_mfcc_train.log --export=none,PATH=/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/chainbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/featbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/fgmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/fstbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/gmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/ivectorbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/kwsbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/latbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/lmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnet2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnet3bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnetbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/online2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/onlinebin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/rnnlmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/sgmm2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/sgmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/tfrnnlmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/cudadecoderbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/utils/:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../tools/openfst/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/python:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/chainbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/featbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/fgmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/fstbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/gmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/ivectorbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/kwsbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/latbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/lmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnet2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnet3bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/nnetbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/online2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/onlinebin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/rnnlmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/sgmm2bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/sgmmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/tfrnnlmbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../src/cudadecoderbin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/utils/:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/../../../tools/openfst/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/python:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/irstlm/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/srilm/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/srilm/bin/i686-m64:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/sequitur-g2p/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/irstlm/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/srilm/bin:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/srilm/bin/i686-m64:/home/kvcper/kaldi/tools/sequitur-g2p/bin --array='1:2' /home/kvcper/kaldi/egs/voxforge/s5/exp/make_mfcc/train/q/make_mfcc_train.sh 2>&1'
and the output was:
'sbatch: error: s_p_parse_file: unable to status file /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf: No such file or directory, retrying in 1sec up to 60sec
 sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file
'
```

Full transcript at https://pastebin.com/J1TD9WNQ

Comment: Do you have access to a SLURM cluster and have the relevant `sbatch` etc. utilities installed on your Kali Linux machine?

Answer (score 1):

The last three lines of output describe precisely where to look for your problem, to wit:

```
and the output was:
'sbatch: error: s_p_parse_file: unable to status file /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf: No such file or directory, retrying in 1sec up to 60sec
 sbatch: fatal: Unable to process configuration file
```

Let us zoom in to the relevant bit:

```
/etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf: No such file or directory
```

One of the required files appears to be missing.